# Avoid duplicating *ngIf Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Calling functions inside the template causes infinite calls

```
<div>{{ renderHtml() }}</div>
```

The same behavior depicts inside `*ngIf` expression

While the template has multiple expressions, writing duplicating `*ngIf` expression inside the template doesn't fit [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

In some angular projects, I have met get method calls in `.ts`

`*ngIf="dryState"`

`get dryState() {return boolean }`

Are getters a proper way to avoid `*ngIf` duplication?
Or the only correct way is to use **pipes**?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but...  the best approach is to avoid function calls at all (besides event handlers). Angular checks the dynamic code (in bindings and interpolations like yours) in every change detection cycle, which can sometimes occur dozens of times per second (eg. on every mouse move). It's better to go with pure pipes (`{{ myData | prepareHtml }}`) or with observables (`{{ myDataAsHtml$ | async }}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getters in a template behave exactly the same as functions in a template, they get called with every change detection. You can easily see this yourself if you put some `console.log` in the getter. So better use properties or pure pipes.